# How to plot two 3D histograms in one figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, histogram, matplotlib-3d

I would like to plot two 3D Histograms in the same figure so as to compare them. I would prefer if the colors were translucent so that the two bars of different colors remain distinguishable to the eye.

I have tried the following code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd
#import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np



xpos = [i*np.ones(8) for i in range(8)]
xpos = np.concatenate(xpos)
ypos = list(np.linspace(0,7,8))
ypos = ypos*8
zpos = np.zeros(64)

xpos2 = xpos
ypos2 = ypos
zpos2 = zpos


dx = np.ones(64)
dy = np.ones(64)
dz = np.random.randint(0,10,64)

dx2 = np.ones(64)
dy2 = np.ones(64)
dz2 = np.random.randint(0,10,64)

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')


ax1.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz, color='b')
ax2.bar3d(xpos2, ypos2, zpos2, dx2, dy2, dz2, color = 'r')
plt.show()
```

I obtain only the red barplot whereas I would like to both the plots interspersed while remaining distinguishable

Comment: In the present state, we can not run your code as we do not possess the '.txt' files. You should provide a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and also state we you obtain and what you want.

Comment: @Liris Thank you for the pointer. I have edited the code accordingly.

Comment: Your `ax1` and `ax2` are on same positions in the figure. Either do two different suplots, ie axes with different positions, or plot the two bar plots on the same ax. In the last case, I can't imagine how it would look like.

Comment: I have tried plotting them on the same ax and the problem is that the plots appear in a mutually exclusive manner i.e., if one plot appears, then another doesn't depending upon your orientation of the 3D plot. I wanted to have them on the same axis but distinguishable so that I may be able to compare.